How to improve sharpness of leaflet map?
I'm working on my first mapping app.  The map on my app is fuzzy compared to the sample online. It's painful to look at because the text isn't sharp.  How do I get the sharpness of the online sample?
Code is at end.


HTML
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="{% static 'map.css' %}"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
      crossorigin=""
    />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script
      src="{% static 'map.js' %}"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>

JS
const url = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}' "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
const layer = L.tileLayer(url, {
  attribution: copy,
});
const map = L.map("map", {
  layers: [layer],
});

map.fitWorld();

